# Trying to send using PHP Mailer and getting following error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

This is my configuration

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "gator4102.hostgator.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = 'test@some.com';
$mail->Password   ='jyghvbjyhj';
```

It throws following error

```
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedLanguage string failed to load: tls
```

Mail gets delivered though sometimes. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$mail->Port       = 465;
```

To:

```
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

For tls, 587 port is used.

Comment: Try $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; with $mail->Port = 465;

Comment: i says coudn't connect to smtp host

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Then your setting should be as following :

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "gator4102.hostgator.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@abc.com";
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get response from server, it's already good enough. This means that you connect to server successfully.

You are probably trying to connect to the port on which another server application is listening. First, check again that you connect to port on which SMTP server is listening and waiting for TLS connection. Try to connect to another server to locate problem. Also, you can try another PHP library.